Auto reload on adding or updating object in django admin
I want to know if there is a way to auto-reload the Django application when adding or updating an object in the Django admin ?
Actually, when I add or update an object, I have to reload my application, and I no longer want this behavior, please

Please don't. Reloading is often a very bad code design.

It means the server is unresponsive, that is is often not very much guaranteed that the server will indeed start. Exactly why do you need this?

I create dynamic models and templates directly from the admin panel. In other words, I generate my models and HTML templates (the views) using the Django admin. However, to ensure that these changes are applied, I have to restart my server.

Please don't: linearize data: create one table with a column about what table it is, and do the routing. Relying on tables is not a good idea.

To set up auto-reloading of your Django application when adding or updating an object in the Django admin, you can use Django signals combined with a bit of JavaScript to refresh the page. Here is a tutorial on How Django Signals Work
You can also refer to the documentation here
You can then use JavaScript to periodically check for changes and reload the page if necessary.As I don't know the logic of your code, you can follow this tutorial on refreshing pages using javascript. Combine these 2 methods according to your own logic and you will be able to automatically reload the page
